# iOS : Cannot find IntentHandler in scope

Tags: ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I am working on project where I have Objective-c and swift files in code ... I am implementing siri shortcut in project. I have to return IntentHandler from IntentHandler Class but its showing that Intenthandler is not in scope.

**IntentHandler** is in Intent extension while CallHomeAwayIntentHandler is out of this folder.

Kindly help how can I access CallHomeAwayIntentHandler in IntentHandler.

[image]

**CallHomeAwayIntentHandler.swift**
[image]

With target info

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show more about `Target Membership` of both files?

Comment: @son Added, seems different target of both files due to extension

Comment: yeah you're right, files come from different modules. I don't know how modules depend on each other. Can you explain?